# pandas: get the percent of a baseline value while baseline and drug are in the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of this kind:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition': ['BL', 'washon', 'washoff', 'BL', 'washon', 'washoff'], 
                   'value': [406, 219, 'NaN', 54, 16, 52]},
                  index = ['cell1', 'cell1', 'cell1', 'cell2', 'cell2', 'cell2'])
```

And I need to loop over the `value` column and get the percent of `BL` for the `washon` and `washoff` values for each `cell1` and `cell2` into a new column, aka

```
df['value_percent_BL'] = [100, 53, NaN, 100, 29, 96]
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: This seems pretty easy to solve, but I'm confused about the rules regarding the outputs. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: the values in df['value_percent_BL'] were completely off, my bad! Hope it makes sense now. BL= baseline and 'washon' is the application of a drug which is removed in 'washoff'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use real NaN, not strings:

```
df = df.replace('NaN', float('nan'))
```

Then get the value of BL per group and divide the value:

```
df['value_percent_BL'] = df['value']/df['value'].where(df['condition'].eq('BL')).groupby(df.index).transform('max')*100
```

output:

```
      condition  value  value_percent_BL
cell1        BL  406.0        100.000000
cell1    washon  219.0         53.940887
cell1   washoff    NaN               NaN
cell2        BL   54.0        100.000000
cell2    washon   16.0         29.629630
cell2   washoff   52.0         96.296296
```

###### rounded values:

```
group = df['value'].where(df['condition'].eq('BL')).groupby(df.index).transform('max')
df['value_percent_BL'] = (df['value']/group*100).round()
```

output:

```
      condition  value  value_percent_BL
cell1        BL  406.0             100.0
cell1    washon  219.0              54.0
cell1   washoff    NaN               NaN
cell2        BL   54.0             100.0
cell2    washon   16.0              30.0
cell2   washoff   52.0              96.0
```

*NB. if you really want floored values: use `numpy.floor`: `np.floor(df['value']/group*100)`*

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to `groupby` on `index`, `apply` a function that finds the ratio of each `value` to `value` corresponding to `BL` in each group. Not as elegant as @mozway's solution but does the job.

```
df['value_percent_BL'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: 100 * x['value'] // x.loc[x['condition']=='BL','value'].iloc[0]).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
      condition  value  value_percent_BL
cell1        BL  406.0             100.0
cell1    washon  219.0              53.0
cell1   washoff    NaN               NaN
cell2        BL   54.0             100.0
cell2    washon   16.0              29.0
cell2   washoff   52.0              96.0
```